# numpy max vs amax vs maximum

Tags: python, numpy, math, max

numpy has three different functions which seem like they can be used for the same things --- except that `numpy.maximum` can *only* be used element-wise, while `numpy.max` and `numpy.amax` can be used on particular axes, or all elements.  Why is there more than just `numpy.max`?  Is there some subtlety to this in performance?

(Similarly for `min` vs. `amin` vs. `minimum`)

Answer (score 259, accepted):

`np.max` is just an alias for `np.amax`. This function only works on a *single* input array and finds the value of maximum element in that entire array (returning a scalar). Alternatively, it takes an `axis` argument and will find the maximum value along an axis of the input array (returning a new array).

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 1, 6],
                  [2, 4, 1]])
>>> np.max(a)
6
>>> np.max(a, axis=0) # max of each column
array([2, 4, 6])
```

The default behaviour of `np.maximum` is to take *two* arrays and compute their element-wise maximum. Here, 'compatible' means that one array can be broadcast to the other. For example:

```
>>> b = np.array([3, 6, 1])
>>> c = np.array([4, 2, 9])
>>> np.maximum(b, c)
array([4, 6, 9])
```

But `np.maximum` is also a [universal function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) which means that it has other features and methods which come in useful when working with multidimensional arrays. For example you can compute the cumulative maximum over an array (or a particular axis of the array):

```
>>> d = np.array([2, 0, 3, -4, -2, 7, 9])
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(d)
array([2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 9])
```

This is not possible with `np.max`.

You can make `np.maximum` imitate `np.max` to a certain extent when using `np.maximum.reduce`:

```
>>> np.maximum.reduce(d)
9
>>> np.max(d)
9
```

Basic testing suggests the two approaches are comparable in performance; and they should be, as [`np.max()` actually calls `np.maximum.reduce`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/core/_methods.py#L16-L28) to do the computation.

Comment: Thanks.  Obviously one can use `amax` for the same (root) purpose as `maximum`, i.e. with `numpy.amax([a1, a2], axis=0)` --- but is this not as optimized for this behavior as `numpy.maximum`?  Similarly, do the added niceties of `numpy.amax` (e.g. the `axis` parameter) preclude it from being a `ufunc`?

Comment: That's right, `amax` is not optimised for of element-wise comparison in this - any input will need to be a Numpy array, so that list would be converted before the operation ran (assuming that the two shapes were the same). The docs for `amax` specifically say that `maximum` is faster here.

Comment: On the second question: I guess `amax` *could* be made into a ufunc, although the main purpose of ufuncs is to allow operations to be broadcast between arrays. There seems little need to make `max` a unary ufunc. I think `amax` existed before ufuncs were really a thing (it came from numeric, NumPy's parent) so is also kept for posterity.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) `maximum.reduce` is preferred for performance: `The Python function max() will find the maximum over a one-dimensional array, but it will do so using a slower sequence interface. The reduce method of the maximum ufunc is much faster. Also, the max() method will not give answers you might expect for arrays with greater than one dimension.` [...]

Comment: @TomHale: I think that documentation is referring to the Python built in `max()` function, rather than `numpy.max()`, but it is definitely worth pointing out that the Python `max()` is slower.

Comment: Isn't there any way to detect which functions are aliases of others? It seems rather ridiculous that Python is so opaque that people are forced to do all sorts of benchmarks to attempt to distinguish the myriad identically named functions floating about.

Answer (score 26):

You've already stated why `np.maximum` is different - it returns an array that is the element-wise maximum between two arrays.

As for `np.amax` and `np.max`: they both call the same function - `np.max` is just an alias for `np.amax`, and they compute the maximum of all elements in an array, or along an axis of an array.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.amax
Out[2]: <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.amax>

In [3]: np.max
Out[3]: <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.amax>
```

Comment: I feel stupid now, I was doing `from numpy import max as np_max` just to avoid conflict with the generic `max` all the time while I could have just used `amax` *hides*.

Answer (score 15):

For completeness, in Numpy there are four *maximum* related functions. They fall into two different categories:

- `np.amax/np.max`, `np.nanmax`: for **single array** order statistics
- and `np.maximum`, `np.fmax`: for element-wise comparison of **two arrays**

---

#### I. [For *single array* order statistics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.statistics.html#order-statistics)

NaNs propagator **`np.amax/np.max`** and its NaN ignorant counterpart **`np.nanmax`**.

- `np.max` is just an alias of `np.amax`, so they are considered as one function.

  ```
  >>> np.max.__name__
  'amax'
  >>> np.max is np.amax
  True
  ```
- `np.max` propagates NaNs while `np.nanmax` ignores NaNs.

  ```
  >>> np.max([np.nan, 3.14, -1])
  nan
  >>> np.nanmax([np.nan, 3.14, -1])
  3.14
  ```

#### II. [For element-wise comparison of *two arrays*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#miscellaneous)

NaNs propagator **`np.maximum`** and its NaNs ignorant counterpart **`np.fmax`**.

- Both functions require two arrays as the first two positional args to compare with.

  ```
  # x1 and x2 must be the same shape or can be broadcast
  np.maximum(x1, x2, /, ...);
  np.fmax(x1, x2, /, ...)
  ```
- `np.maximum` propagates NaNs while `np.fmax` ignores NaNs.

  ```
  >>> np.maximum([np.nan, 3.14, 0], [np.NINF, np.nan, 2.72])
  array([ nan,  nan, 2.72])
  >>> np.fmax([np.nan, 3.14, 0], [np.NINF, np.nan, 2.72])
  array([-inf, 3.14, 2.72])
  ```
- The element-wise functions are [`np.ufunc`(**Universal Function**)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), which means they have some special properties that normal Numpy function don't have.

  ```
  >>> type(np.maximum)
  <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
  >>> type(np.fmax)
  <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
  >>> #---------------#
  >>> type(np.max)
  <class 'function'>
  >>> type(np.nanmax)
  <class 'function'>
  ```

---

And finally, the same rules apply to the four *minimum* related functions:

- `np.amin/np.min`, `np.nanmin`;
- and `np.minimum`, `np.fmin`.

Answer (score 3):

`np.maximum` not only compares elementwise but also compares array elementwise with single value

```
>>>np.maximum([23, 14, 16, 20, 25], 18)
array([23, 18, 18, 20, 25])
```