# Calculating maximum values with numpy

Tags: python

I am new to python and was just wondering if someone could explain to me the difference between using `np.amax` and `np.max`.

I am trying to pull out the maximum frequency value from a spectrogram (the frequency axis being 1) and I am struggling to understand which code I should use and I don't really see the differences from the help info.

I would really appreciate any tips you could give me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a difference: `np.max` is an alias for `np.amax`.

See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html

Or: [numpy max vs amax vs maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569668/numpy-max-vs-amax-vs-maximum)

Comment: thank you! I was getting really confused as some of the scipy docs were saying different things, but thanks for the links, it helped clarify this for me!