# What is the difference between max(my_array) and my_array.max()

Tags: python, numpy, methods, syntax

For example, if I define my array as `my_array = np.array([1,2,3])`,

What is the difference between 
`max(my_array)`and 
`my_array.max()` ?

Is this one of those cases where one is 'syntactic sugar' for the other? Also, why does the first one work with a Python list, but the second doesn't?

Comment: The first one is [`__builtin__.max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and the other one is [`numpy.ndarray.max`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)

Comment: See also: [numpy max vs amax vs maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569668/numpy-max-vs-amax-vs-maximum)

Comment: `[1,2,3].max()` gives an error that explains why it doesn't work.  `max` method is not defined for lists.  An `AttributeError` like this is basic Python, so you need to learn its significance well.

Answer (score 1):

As people have stated in the comments of your question, they are referencing two different functions.

`max(my_array)` is a built in Python function available to any sequence data in python.

Whereas, `my_array.max()` is referencing a function within the object. In this case my_array is from the Numpy array class. Numpy does not recognize the list data type for this function. However, this method will provide a speed improvement over the `max(my_array)` whenever you are using numpy data sequences.

As a rule of thumb if the variable has a `variable.someMethod()` the function is a method and is specific to the class of object. If the function is called as `function(variable)` then the function is either a part of the python distribution or the file/class you are working with.