# Get the value at a position from all layers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 3 numpy arrays of shape `(224, 224, 20)`. I want to go through each of `(224, 224)` values in all 20 layers (dimensions) and compare them to get the highest among them. For 3 Dimensional, I am able to come up with this:

```
arr1 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[10,11,12],[15,16,17]]])
for x in range(0,2):                                                                                                            
       for y in range(0,2):                                                                                                            
             print(arr1[:,x,y])
```

But, I somehow couldn't understand how to convert it for (224,224,20) shaped arrays. 
I also need the index of the layer which contains the maximum value.

Comment: You only have to replace range(0,2) with range(0, len(arr1)) etc

Comment: Just use `max` along the alst axis? `arr1.max(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `numpy.max` instead of a for loop:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html

```
np.max(arr1, axis=2)
```

To get the index, use `numpy.argmax`

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

```
np.argmax(arr1, axis=2)
```

Comment: Got it, but what if I need to know the index of the layer with the maximum value?

Comment: I am just curious, is there any difference between numpy.max and numpy.amax. All i see on internet is numpy.max is just an alias of numpy.amax. But, is there any difference either in terms of performance or anyother factors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569668/numpy-max-vs-amax-vs-maximum

Answer (score 2):

To get max values along one dimension, you can use `numpy.amax`, checkout:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html