# How can I index each occurrence of a max value along a given axis of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max, vectorization

Suppose I have the following numpy array.

```
Q = np.array([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[0,2,0])
```

**Question:** How do I identify the position of each max value along axis 1? So the desired output would be something like:

```
array([[1,2],[0,2],[1]]) # The dtype of the output is not required to be a np array.
```

With np.argmax I can identify the first occurrence of the maximum along the axis, but not the subsequent values.

```
In: np.argmax(Q, axis =1) 
Out: array([1, 0, 1])
```

I've also seen answers that rely on using np.argwhere that use a term like this.

```
np.argwhere(Q == np.amax(Q))
```

This will also not work here because I can't limit argwhere to work along a single axis.  I also can't just flatten out the np array to a single axis because the max's in each row will differ.  I need to identify each instance of the max of each row.

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this without looping through each row of the entire array, or is there a function analogous to np.argwhere that accepts an axis argument?

Any insight would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `np.where`:

```
np.where(Q == Q.max(axis=1)[:,None])
```

Output:

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([1, 2, 0, 2, 1]))
```

Not quite the output you want, but contains equivalent information.

You can also use `np.argwhere` which gives you the zip data:

```
np.argwhere(Q==Q.max(axis=1)[:,None])
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```

Comment: oh awesome thanks alot! This is a really basic question but would you mind explaining what function the [:, None] is playing?  Still trying to get the hang of this.  Also I just want to clarify is there a distinction between max and amax?

Comment: @phntm `[:,None]` thing is call [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.). `.max` and `.amax` are [the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569668/numpy-max-vs-amax-vs-maximum).