# np.max not returning correct output when used on intergers

Tags: python, numpy

In Python, why does

```
np.max(-2,0)
```

return

```
-2
```

when

```
max(-2, 0)
```

returns

```
0
```

Should they not have the same output for integers? Or is np.max used for something else?

Comment: I recommend you read the docstring for `numpy.max`. The you seem to misunderstand what the second argument is

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569668/numpy-max-vs-amax-vs-maximum

Comment: Yeah, its a little strange at first blush, but it's quite different from python max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input value to the `np.max()` function must be a list, please take a look at the official `Numpy` documentation to know more about its functions, inputs and outputs:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.max([-2, 0]))
```

**`Output:`**

```
0
```